# Angular select does not populate options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, bootstrap-4

I am trying to learn nodejs. I have a simple application where I have defined an array `options` in `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  options = ["Option1", "Option2"];
}
```

and I am trying to expose the options as dropdown app.component.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    {{options}}!
    <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="app-root">
      <option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option}}">{{option}}</option>
    </select>
  </h1>
```

For some reason the selectbox is not getting populated. If I print the options I can clearly see that it print fine.
Here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: i think you mixed both angularjs and angular 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" >
      <option *ngFor="let option of options;" value="{{option}}">{{option}}</option>
    </select>
  </h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [*ngFor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) . Because you are using angular 4. There is no ng-repeat directive in angular 2/4/5.

```
<option *ngFor="let option of options" value="{{option}}">{{option}}</option>
```

Comment: You were right on but without the `**let** option of options` it doesn't work Thanks for pointing the obvious to the newbee.